# C# Run a check for each row inside the dataGridView and update it instantly after check

Tags: c#

I'm currently loading a text file containing words (Wordlist) into a `dataGridView`. After the data is uploaded to the `dataGridView` the user would be able to click a button which would get the HTML content of a website. Now the `dataGridView` would update it's own row cell content.

Example screenshot: [Screenshot link hosted using gyazo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL3BZ.png)

Sadly all rows will update at the same time, once each `dataGridView` row was checked. But I want it to update each row instantly after the check for the current row was done.

What am I doing wrong or how could I archive this?

**Function code to check each row in the dataGridView:**

```
private void bunifuFlatButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int count = 0; count < dataGridView1.RowCount; count++)
    {
        try
        {
            string urlAddress = "http://twitter.com/" + dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value;
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string htmlCode = client.DownloadString(urlAddress);
                getUserLinks(htmlCode);

                for (int i = 0; i < userLinks.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (userLinks[i].Contains("myspace.com") || userLinks[i].Contains("last.fm"))
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value = userLinks[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError && ex.Response != null)
            {
                var resp = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response;
                if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried refreshing or updating after each record? I will slow down the time it takes to iterate though. datagridview1.update();
datagridview1.refresh();

Comment: Works perfect with dataGridView1.Update(); Thank you!

Comment: I'll respond with the answer then incase it helps others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried refreshing or updating after each record? I will slow down the time it takes to iterate though.

```
datagridview1.update(); 
datagridview1.refresh();
```